# Session variable is not working in readfile php method

Tags: php, session-variables, readfile

I've the php code as below. 
The variable `$_SESSION['url']` has value and printing as it is.
Its not working if I called the session variable.

```
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile($_SESSION['url']);
```

But Its working, If we wrote as below.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['url']= 'http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile($_SESSION['url']);
```

if anybody experienced this, how to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: any reason you set `'url'` in your second sample, but read from `'foo'`? Did you confirm via `var_dump($_SESSION)` in your first example that `'url'` is actually set?

Comment: Use if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) to make sure that the session is actually existing.

Comment: @MarcB sorry, Please see the updated question. We confirmed with var_dump too

Comment: @Jonast92 Its existing, and printing if we use var_dump

Comment: It sounds like the server doesn't write the session, have you access to the session folder to check this ?

Comment: @AurélienGrimpard session var has value and **its printing in both codes**, the only thing is _its not working when I'm trying to read the file straight from_ `$_SESSION['url']`

Answer (score 1):

The `$_SESSION` is variable (almost) like any other for duration of the script. So if you write it on one line of the script, you can read it later. No matter if sessions work or not in your environment.

So it's not surprising that your second example works. And it does not show anything that could help explaining your problem.

You should show us instead, what did you try to do to make sessions working. And where and how do you actually set the `url` session variable?

Comment: the $_SESSION['url'] is not passing to the google docs viewer,

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what you mean by your comment.